# When do I use inversions in an array?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

In problems like the 15 Tile Problem or Larry's Array problem, we use inversions in the array as a method to solve.

But what's the principle behind this method and how do I know when to use inversions?

Comment: What do you mean by "inversions in an array"?

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/inversion-of-array-1587115620/1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation